# Displaying 3D models in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native, 3d

My goal is to make a page with a 3D model in my React Native app, 
the most easiest way I found is to use `expo-three` library. 
But it requires `Expo`, so this isn't an option in my case. 
What else can I use to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are other few options for you to display 3D model (without using Expo) in react native application:

- React-native-3d-model-view
- React-native-gl-model-view
- Using threeJS in react-native
- Using [this](https://medium.com/@yoobi55/creating-3d-sphere-component-with-react-native-and-three-c5fb46dadbd) tutorial to show your 3D Model

It depends on your requirements like which 3D model file (.OBJ, ASC, Quake 2 MD2, Autodesk 3DS etc.) you're going to show in your app.